# Geoserver WMS pre-render

Tags: geoserver, wms

i publish a WMS Layer with data from a MySQL Database using geoserver. At the moment it seems like geoserver is rendering the WMS Layer on the fly. Is there a way to "pre-render" periodically - e.g. hourly - and just call for the "cached" one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to enable [GeoWebCache (GWC)](https://geowebcache.org) to make a cache of your layer. Infact GeoServer does this automatically for you when you publish a layer unless you ask it not to. However, to take advantage of this cache you need to make sure your clients are all making identical requests (when viewing the same area). GeoServer (and the rest of the WMS world) handles this by breaking your map into tiles and using the [WMTS standard](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts) to serve them out. You can find the relevant getCapabilities link (to pass to your client) on your GeoServer home page.

As for refreshing tiles periodically you would need to investigate the [GWC rest API](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/rest/index.html)